# What is 'hitnodes.php' on a GoDaddy shared hosting server?

Tags: php, godaddy, shared-hosting

At my company, our website is hosted with GoDaddy's shared hosting service. I was tidying up the html folder today and noticed a file called `hitnodes.php` which I hadn't noticed before. It was only 16 lines long, and the code seemed innocuous, and just printed out the hostname of the server we're on and a bunch of dots.

I was pretty sure we didn't put it there, which lead me to believe it was from GoDaddy, so I called their support to see if they knew what it was. The guy I talked to just said "oh, I'll delete that", and when I asked what it was, he said that he wasn't allowed to tell me (!), and that he had just deleted it. When I pressed him as to why there was a file in *our* site that he couldn't tell us about, he just said it had to do with server maintenance and he couldn't tell me anything else about it.

So half out of concern that this could be part of some exploit that he didn't want to spook me about, and half out of pure curiosity, I've been trying to find out what this script is for, but the most I could turn up was [this page](http://angryhoneybadger.com/work/hitnodes/) talking about a method to quickly check for errors on a 4GH or Grid system. I didn't really follow what the author of that blog was talking about, and I was hoping that someone here might have a good explanation for the purpose of this script and how it works, and maybe some idea of why the GoDaddy representative was being so cagey about it. If it was just to check if a node was having problems, why not say "Oh, that was so we could quickly see if the server was having problems."? Not exactly state secrets...

Here's the code reproduced for your scrutiny:

```
<?php
    if ( $_SERVER["OS"] == "Windows_NT" ) {
        $hostname = strtolower($_SERVER["COMPUTERNAME"]);
    } else {
        $hostname = `hostname`;
        $hostnamearray = explode('.', $hostname);
        $hostname = $hostnamearray[0];
    }
    if ( !preg_match("/[0-9]{2,4}/", $hostname, $match) ) die("Failed to detect node");
    $node = $match[0];
    if ( preg_match("/^0/", $node) ) $node += 1000;
    header("Content-Length: " . $node);
    $response = $hostname . "<br />Padding: ";
    $response = $response . str_repeat('.', $node - strlen($response));
    echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/xurizaemon/f5de7fa8ef6639c45157 is what appears to be equivalent code for IIS, found via Google.

Comment: Yeah, I found a couple of other similar code snippets via Google on other people's sites, but none of them had much in the way of explanation...

Comment: I think the linked blog post explains it pretty well. Maybe they're super staff aren't empowered to discuss motivations ... You would think they could spare a virtual host per node rather than hijacking customer domains, but that may be one of their lesser offenses :)

Comment: I guess what I specifically don't understand from the blog post is how the output of the script is useful for debugging node issues. What kinds of issues is it supposed to diagnose?

Comment: @KerriganJoseph I still have a 4G hosting account with them (most have been upgraded to their new cPanel accounts), and have seen this in the past. As the link in your post explains, it's just for their hosting department to test nodes periodically to make sure they're reachable. I'm sure the rep didn't want to elaborate more because putting files in costumer accounts is usually not very well received, and I suppose it could be used to test if a hack or DDoS was successful or not. It seems fairly innocuous, so wouldn't worry about it (just delete it).

Comment: @KerriganJoseph Done, with a little more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a file used by GoDaddy's hosting department to periodically test if accounts on their Fourth-Generation Hosting (4GH) systems are reachable. 4GH was GoDaddy's precursor to cloud hosting, as can be read about [here](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4883/web-hosting-frequently-asked-questions):

> Web Hosting "pools" the resources of many servers and your site's
>   content resides on multiple servers. This networked system helps
>   achieve a high reliability—beyond 99.9%—for your website because if
>   one server shuts down, only a fraction of the total resources are
>   lost.

In this system configuration, each account can be accessed via a 4 different *nodes* on a *grid* hosting system (hence the abbreviation *4GH*), allowing for redundancy and performance increases via load balancing over standard hosting.

The *hitnodes.php* script for Linux (and *hitnodes.aspx* for Windows) is aptly named, since it's used by their hosting department to see if sites are reachable (i.e., can be "hit") on these nodes. By taking a look at the page size returned by this script, their IT department (and you as well), can see what node a site is being served on. Most 4GH accounts end up getting migrated to different server configurations depending on usage (as an upgrade), so they likely use this script for gauging that as well.

I've seen this file in accounts before, and as the GoDaddy representative relayed, it can just be deleted without any consequences. I'm sure the rep did not want to elaborate further on how this script is used because placing files in accounts is usually not very well received by customers, and I suppose it could be used to test if a hack or DDoS was successful for a particular node/server.

I do not think 4GH accounts are sold by GoDaddy anymore, since they've replaced them with cPanel (for Linux) and Plesk (for Windows) accounts instead of using their in-house control panel, so this file likely won't be seen as much in the future.